epplus with clearFormula
I have a question about epplus
clearFormulas(). I have a formula and only want the values ​​from the formula, unfortunately I can't do it with clearFormula().
No error is displayed, but the formulas are no longer there in Excel, but there are no values ​​there either? Can someone help me? Here is an excerpt from:
I tried the following code, but unfortunately without success.
sheetPayPal.Calculate();
for (int i = 2; i <= (iLastRowPayPal - 1); i++)
{
   if (sheetPayPal.Cells[i, 20].Value != null)
   {
       string? strOrderNr = sheetPayPal.Cells[i, 20].Value.ToString();
       sheetPayPal.Cells[i, 40].FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-20], " + "\"" + strOrderNr + "\"" + ")";
       sheetPayPal.ClearFormulas();
   }
}

I used Excel.Interop to avoid the following code:
Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = xlApp.WorksheetFunction;
for (int i = 2; i < x; i++)
{
string strOrderNr = wsPayPal.Cells[i, 20].Value;
Excel.Range s = wsPayPal.Cells.Find(What: strOrderNr, Type.Missing, LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);
double resultOrderNr = wsf.CountIf(wsPayPal.Range["T:T"], s);
}

Is there something similar in epplus?
Best regards
WDani

Are you trying to insert formulas into cells, have them be calculated, and then, once the calculations are done, clear the formulas and leave the values behind? If so, sorry, I can't imagine that that is possible. Remember, you are writing a file, not telling Excel what to do. Excel will only perform the calculations once it Opens the file. By that point, your code to write the file is long gone. If you can put up with a macro filled Excel file, you could right a macro to run after the file is open. I'm not sure how well that would work, but I suspect the user experience would suck (security)
